# React-query: useQueryClient doesn't update

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm trying to mutate data in loop in one component and then use query client data in another one. Example code:
Component 1:

```
const promises = [];

items.forEach(i =>
  promises.push(
    mutateAsync({ id: i }).then(data =>
      queryClient.setQueryData([MY_DATA, { id: i }], data),
    ),
  ),
);

await Promise.all(promises);
```

Then in another component I'm trying to use useQueryClient

Component 2:

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient();
```

If I check queryClient.getQueriesData(MY_DATA) in first component, everything is fine and updated data is shown. In second one there is no update.

Am I doing something wrong? Or should I somehow listen for queryClient changes?